# how to take multiple strings as input and store them in a 2d array using c?

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

The following is my code written in c language where I am trying to take strings as input and store them in a 2d array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    int i,j,n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char a[n][n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf(" %[^\n]",a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s\n",a[i]);
    }
}
```

below is my input
4
1112
1912
1892
1234

my excepted output should look like below
1112
1912
1892
1234

the output which I am getting is below
1112191218921234
191218921234
18921234
1234

can anyone explain what is wrong in my code? any help would be appreciated! thanks:)

Comment: Hint: an array of length 4 cannot hold a string of length 4, the space for nul-terminator is not there.

Comment: Also, beware while using array as strings, they need null-termination to work.

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]",a[i]);` is worse than  [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
char a[n][n];
```

Into:

```
char a[n][n + 1];
```

For a null-terminator. Without that, the char array won't be terminated and keep printing.

You'll get the correct output afterwards:

```
$ gcc -o prog prog.c; ./prog
4
1112
1912
1892
1234
```

Comment: and the outer dimension can very well stay as `n`.

Comment: @RohanBari, then better to delete these comments.  Mine already erased.